# Dealing with the count function

Tags: mysql

My Boss want to know how many times each of these shipping number of days occurred. Ordered by number of days DESC.
So far have :

```
SELECT DateDiff(shippedDate,orderDate) As '#Days', COUNT(*) 
  FROM datenumtest
```

I think I need condition, can someone help me out with this?

Comment: Can you provide a sample data set and expected output?

Answer (score 1):

Calculate the `DateDiff` across all records first in a data set `r`, then you can do the grouping on that data set which becomes data set `r1` then sort the `r1` data set:

```
select r.NumDays, count(1) as the_count
from (
  SELECT DateDiff(shippedDate,orderDate) as 'NumDays' 
  FROM datenumtest
) r
group by r.NumDays
order by r.NumDays desc;
```

Comment: Why do you need the outer subquery?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Your right, i'll update. I've had issues with Oracle db in the past sorting a grouped data set - so I tend to this way 2nd nature.

Comment: Good on you, I think this is what the OP wants, hard to see this given the state of the question.